# Python file renamer with if statements

Tags: python

I have a folder full of .xlsx files that are named to a specific file format such as FW2014516 MS1 T3 - GHD.xlsx, however, some files have this format FW2014516 MS1 - GHD.xlsx I want to be able to loop through the whole folder and rename each file to a new format such as FW2014516_MS1_T3_GHD, if the "T3" value exists(if may not actually be T3, it could be WT3).

Any help is appreciated.

Here is what i have so far.

```
import os
import re


os.chdir(r"C:\folder where data is")
# print(os.getcwd())

for f in os.listdir():
    file_name, file_ext = (os.path.splitext(f))
    
    file_name = file_name.strip()
    print(file_name)
    # # print(file_name.split(''))
    print(re.split(r'[\s|-]\s*', file_name))
    f_name1, f_name2, f_fname3, f_name4, f_name5 = re.split(r'[\s|-]\s*', file_name)
#Need some type of if statement needed here?
new_name = '{}_{}_{}_{}{}'.format(f_name1, f_name2, f_name3, f_name4, file_ext)
os.rename(f, new_name)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could state your specific question. For what question are you looking for an answer?

Comment: I'm new to using python. Also, I stated in the original question what I wanted. I want to be able to loop through the whole folder and rename each file to a new format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of "_".join() and .split() :

```
lst_filename = [r"FW2014516 MS1 T3 - GHD.xlsx",
r"FW2014516 MS1 - GHD.xlsx"]

lst = []
for filename in lst_filename:
    if " T3 " in filename or " WT3 " in filename:
        new_filename = "_".join(filename.replace("-", "").split())
    else:
        new_filename = filename
    
    lst.append(new_filename)

print(lst)
#['FW2014516_MS1_T3_GHD.xlsx', 'FW2014516 MS1 - GHD.xlsx']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import os
import re


os.chdir(r"C:\folder where data is")
# print(os.getcwd())

for f in os.listdir():
    file_name, file_ext = (os.path.splitext(f))
    
    file_name = file_name.strip()
    print(file_name)
    # # print(file_name.split(''))
    if (' T3-' in file_name) or (' WT3-' in file_name):
        new_name = re.sub('[- ]+', '_', file_name) + file_ext
        os.rename(f, new_name)
        print(f'Renamed {f} to {new_name}.')
```